# Using mx components in spark skins

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex3, skinning

Since `fontSharpness` and `fontThickness` don't work in Flex 4, as it says [here](http://forums.adobe.com/message/3632979) (though I'd like to be proven wrong), I have replaced every `<s:Label/>` in my application with `<mx:Label/>`.

Though it works well in panels and dialogs, it doesn't work in skins.
When I add skin parts to skins, they should extend a predefined class.
Say for `promptDisplay` in `TextInputSkin` I cannot use this:

```
<mx:Label id="promptDisplay"/>
```

where this:

```
<s:Label id="promptDisplay"/>
```

is supposed to be, because `promptDisplay` should extend an `IDisplayText`.

What is the best workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I suppose the quickest workaround would be to create your own Label class by subclassing mx `Label` and implementing `IDisplayText`. Something like this:

```
import mx.controls.Label;

public class MyLabel extends Label implements IDisplayText {

    public function get isTruncated():Boolean {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Now you can use `MyLabel` wherever an `IDisplayText` is required and apply `fontSharpness` and `fontThickness` to it, since those two styles are inherited.
Be warned though that this will not work if a `TextBase` is required.

Comment: Didn't think that it may be that easy!! Thank you very much!